# Scrape next pages automatically using for loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this issue with Scrapy and Python code that is currently scraping either first page or the last page. In other words, issue is either the first or the last paginated set of products from total of 3000 are being returned and written to Excel. **I need the query to repeat the extract for **all** the subsequent pages.** As the URL changes to next page, it increments in 120 increments (showing 120 products at a time) until pagination reaches the end of the 3000 products for sale.

> "https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss"
> "https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?s=120"
> "https://boston.craigslist.org/search/sss?s=240"

```
    import Scrapy
    import xlsxwriter 
    class SalesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sales'
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = []
    for x in range(120, 3000,120):
    url = 'https://boston.craigslist.org/d/for-sale/search/' + "sss?s=%s"%str(x)
    start_urls.append(url)
    def parse(self, response):
       titles = response.xpath('//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').extract()
       prices = response.xpath('//span[@class="result-price"]/text()').extract()
       totalcount=response.xpath('//span[@class="totalcount"]/text()').extract()
       total=totalcount[1] 
        row=0
        row_two=-1
        column=0
        workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('Items.xlsx')
        worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
          for i in titles:
            worksheet.write(row,column,i)
             row+=2
          for j in range(0, len(prices)):
           if j % 2:
           worksheet.write(row_two,column+1,prices[j])             
                    row_two+=1        
            workbook.close()
```

Comment: Please, fix your indentation.

Comment: You create a new worksheet with the same name in each iteration. This overwrites your previous versions. Don't write the worksheet in every iteration but keep a long list of titles and prices you extend in each run. When the loop is finished and all the data is in large lists, write them all at once (or write them in each iteration, to be safe, but keep the old records).